# Angular8 Scroll to bottom not working on Safari 12

Tags: scroll, safari, angular8

I have this code that will detect the scroll when reached the bottom of the page.

```
    @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
      onScroll(): void {
        if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY === document.body.scrollHeight) {
          document.querySelector('.button').classList.add('sticky-bottom-margin');
          console.log("Bottom");
        } 
      }
```

I have a sticky button below on my page and the "sticky-bottom-margin" class will have a CSS bottom margin value so that when reached the bottom page, the footer will not be covered or hidden. However, when I tried this in Ipad Mini 2019 safari 12. it doesn't work. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. Instead of using the ***document.querySelector('.button').classList.add('sticky-bottom-margin');*** to add a class on my sticky button. I just added an boolean variable if the page reached the bottom of the page and once the boolean is true then I add a class on my sticky button in the html.

HTML:

```
<div class="sticky-save-button" [class.sticky-bottom-margin]="bottomScroll">
     <button mat-button class="btn-primary"> Save </button>
</div>
```

TS:

```
 @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
  onScroll(): void {
    this.bottomScroll = false;
    if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
      this.bottomScroll = true;
    }
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

Thanks!